# Android Java R.layout.balloon_overlay cannot be resolved or is not a field- android error

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have in, an android project, in res/layout folder a balloon_overlay.xml file. I recieve an error that the resource file cannot be resolved or is not a field. I do have android.R correctly referenced in my activity file where I use the resource file but I can't seem to find out what the problem is or how to fix it. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/balloon_main_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/balloon_overlay_bg_selector"
    android:minWidth="200dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="25dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="0dip"
    android:paddingTop="0dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/balloon_inner_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="40dip"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/balloon_item_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="balloon_item_title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
                android:textSize="16dip" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/balloon_item_snippet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="balloon_item_snippet"
                android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light"
                android:textSize="12dip" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/balloon_disclosure"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingTop="3dip"
            android:src="@drawable/balloon_disclosure"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/balloon_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"

        android:src="@drawable/balloon_overlay_close" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: A few questions first of all.
Are you using eclipse?
What are the imports in the file?
What is the line of code that is problematic?
What exactly is the error message?
There is no error in the xml file?

Comment: Using Eclipse and I have Android.R imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `android.R` but your own `R` class (which is automatically generated in the `gen` folder and contains the constants for your resources. In Eclipse, pressing *Strg+Shift+O* should organize your imports correctly.